# javascript error during loading of latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to load latitude and longitude value using this code but I receive back this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: position is not defined
(anonymous function)
```

here is the code I used in the head of html:

```
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        get_location();
    });

    function get_location()
    {
        if(navigator.geolocation)
        {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

                    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

            });
        }
    }

    console.log(position.coords);
</script>
```

I forgot something ?

Comment: I think you need to add a position parameter to the callback function ie getCurrentPosition( function( position ){ ...

Comment: I added position but when I try console.log(position.coords) I got Uncaught ReferenceError: position is not defined
(anonymous function)

Comment: If position is still undefine perhaps the api is unable to get your location, try adding the second error callback and see if that is called, btw I'm just using goole search, I dont know the google maps api only played with the openmaps.

Comment: console.log(position.coords); outside of the function get_location()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(){...}
```

must be

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){...}
```

You can add callback errorHandle to get errorCode

More info http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#geolocation

Comment: I corrected it...but as I commented I receive another error...some idea?